# how can I set one variable stored string in the 1st batch file and use the 2nd batch file to show the variable correctly?

Tags: batch-file

I'm so sorry for asking this question, I'm a beginner, but after I searched on the Internet for 3 days I still can't find solution. Now I have a question that describe below.

I have two batch files. The 1st batch file is as below:

**print.bat**

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^& echo.
echo %1%
```

This batch file is for showing string have line feeds(to show multiple lines). The string is just the 1st parameter(%1).

And then I have 2nd batch file. Just accept two parameters and then set variable called frac. The main goal is to create a string with line feeds.

**frac.bat**

```
set "frac=  %1  !LF!-----!LF!  %2  "
```

Then, I open the cmd window and type

```
frac 2 3
```

and I use the echo command to check it

```
echo %frac%
```

and it shows like below:

```
  2  !LF!-----!LF!  3
```

which is what I want. But when I use this as a parameter to pass to the 1st batch file

```
print %frac%
```

but it just shows

```
2
```

why not it doesn't show like below

```
  2  
-----
  3
```

how can I correct the code to let it show correctly?

The main usage of print.bat is accept a variable which stored a string with !LF! (this equal to line feed as I defined in print.bat). So every %1 parameter of print.bat should include "!LF!", and now what I want to do is expand !LF! to "^& echo." , let it can show multiple line on cmd screen. And frac.bat is the batch file to produce a string with "!LF!" and stored into a variable, then pass it to print.bat and show it. Of course, I have other batch files haven't done yet, but they all have the same purpose.
So the main point is how to correct the code in print.bat , how to let it show multiple lines correctly?

Comment: If "The string is just the 1st parameter(%1)", then use `%1` and not `%1%`. You should also explain your use of `print`, (is it the basename of a third party utility, or batch file)?

Comment: I should ask, where did you find a reference explaining that ```set LF=^& echo.``` is how to define a variable named `LF` with a linefeed as its value?

Comment: @Compo print is the abbreviation of print.bat , it's not a third party utility, and the main purpose of print.bat is to print the string that have line feeds from other batch files. For example, I have to deal something other tasks and then pass the string to print.bat and show it on cmd. You may ask why I don't show it directly on frac.bat , because later I will write other bach files to deal with other works, not simply only have frac.bat and print.bat , actually hve other like sqrt.bat nroot.bat subscript.ba supscript.bat ect.. , something that I can layout ascii art for math.

Comment: @Compo LF it's just a variable name which represented ^&echo. , because if I want to show multiple lines , I have to use & echo. to show it , so that't why I have to make some strings inn other batch files and then pass it to print.bat

Comment: It may be worth mentioning also that batch files are unlikely to be able to perform arithmetic functions with much accuracy. The common method is to use the `Set` command, with its `/A` option. However as it is only capable of working with decimals as 32-bit integers, not floating points. A simple fraction like `2/3` would resolve to `0`, not `0.66667` (to five decimal places). For that reason, you may be better advised to halt your current thinking, and seek another scripting language for the entire project, before you dive into a very deep pool.

Comment: I see that you've confirmed that `print` should really be `print.bat`, so for that reason, have you tried using `call print` instead, and as long as variable expansion is still enabled in that script, `!frac!` would still be defined.

Comment: @Compo Yeah, I know that, What I do is just write some batch files to show ascii art in cmd windows only. For example, if I call sqrt.bat with number or  more complicated form ( with fractions , fractions of fractions,...), then I can show the ascii art of math  , I don't want to calculate it actually. Just write some batch files to show ascii art of math.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, this is how I'd consider doing it:

**example.cmd**

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set ^"divider=^

-----^

^"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo   2  !divider!  3
EndLocal

Pause
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

Comment: Oh, thank you for replying me. I think I have to explain more about my goal. The main usage of print.bat is accept a variable which stored a string with !LF! (this equal to line feed as I defined in print.bat). So every **%1** parameter of print.bat should include "!LF!", and now what I want to do is expand !LF! to "^& echo." , let it can show multiple line on cmd screen. And frac.bat is the batch file to produce a string with "!LF!" and stored into a variable, then pass it to print.bat and show it. Of course, I have other batch files haven't done yet, but they are the same purpost.

Comment: I don't want to show it directly in frac.bat, because I have to pass it to other batch files to produce other strings with "!LF!" , so the main point is how to correct the print.bat to let it show multiple lines correctly.

Comment: @LessonWang, I'm not sure why my answer does not show you the methodology to define a variable with a line feed. You'd just use ```Set ^"LF=^```, followed by an empty line, followed by ```^"```, to create a variable named `LF`. It seems to me that your actual question may be 'How do I pass line feed characters within an argument string from one batch file to another'.

Comment: I tried that but it stayed the same, yeah I think so, how can I pass the argument string from one batch to another

Comment: Did you read [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77530058/how-can-i-set-one-variable-stored-string-in-the-1st-batch-file-and-use-the-2nd-b?noredirect=1#comment136685213_77530058) under the main question about using `call`? It will mean that your second script can use variables defined in the original script. That way you will not need to pass the variable as an argument at all.

Comment: Oh I got it, you mean I don't need pass the variables as parameter, instead, I just defined it and then call print.bat to echo it

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple small errors.

**print.bat:**

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ^"LF=^
%Don't remove this line%
^"
echo %~1
```

**frac.bat:**

```
@echo off

set "frac=  %1  !LF!-----!LF!  %2  "
```

Session example:

```
C:\Users\Antonio> frac 2 3

C:\Users\Antonio> echo %frac%
  2  !LF!-----!LF!  3

C:\Users\Antonio> print "%frac%"
  2
-----
  3
```

You can not mix in a variable *characters* with *commands*. Insert just characters and show they with `echo` command, or insert just commands and show they with *no* command, but the values are very different in each case.

In this example, the value of `LF` variable is *just* the LineFeed (ASCII 10) character, that will be displayed correctly via `!LF!` Delayed Expansion. If the variable would contain *commands* (separated by `&`), it must be expanded via `%LF%` standard expansion, but in this case the ASCII 10 control character would not be correctly displayed.

If the value of `%frac%` is   `2  !LF!-----!LF!  3`, then it *must* be passed enclosed between quotes; otherwise, the value will be split at each space.

In `print.bat` the parameter must be displayed via `%~1` in order to eliminate the quotes inserted in the call